# How do I skip the 1st 15 milliseconds of NimaActor Animation in Flutter

Tags: animation, dart, flutter

I have been trying to add NimaAnimation to my project but unfortunately my Animation is such that it comes from outside the screen to the center of the screen. And for Nima Animation, it first renders the image and then starts the animation. Is there a way that I can skip the 1st 15 milliseconds of the animation.

The code that I have written for this is:

```
class WelcomeScreenState extends State<WelcomeScreen> {

      bool delayed;

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    new Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 6200), (){
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/tab');
        setState(() {
                  delayed = true;
                });
      });  
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    MediaQueryData media = MediaQuery.of(context);

    var size = media.size;

    // TODO: implement build
    return (delayed == true ) ? new TabHome() : new Scaffold(
        body: new Container(
          height: size.height,
          width: size.width,
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.purple,
            ),
            child: new Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Container(
                    height: size.height * 0.5,
                    width: size.width,
                    child: new NimaActor(
                        "assets/quack",
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                        animation: 'welcome with hello',
                        mixSeconds: 0.1,
                      ),),
                ])));
  }
}
```

Comment: That's quite broad. We don't even see your code. But you may want to use a `Curve`, such as [Interval](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/animation/Interval-class.html)

Comment: Thanks. Tried applying this using tween and it worked.